# Xamarin Forms - can't update Picker

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

The following Xamarin Forms app that contains a `Picker` and a `CollectionView` controls bound to the same `List` of animals (`Chicken` and `Cow`).  When I push the upgrade button the animals should upgrade to an `Eagle` and `Elephant`.  The animals are upgraded, but the Picker doesn't reflect the change.  The `CollectionView` works fine.

What am I doing wrong here?  If needed, the source for this project can be found [at Github](https://github.com/JohnLivermore/SampleXamarinApp/tree/upgradeAnimals).

**Click to see demo**

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQILA.jpg)

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                 mc:Ignorable="d"
                 x:Class="SampleApp.MainPage">

        <StackLayout Margin="0,100,0,0">
            <Button Text="Upgrade Animals" 
                    Margin="10"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                    Command="{Binding Upgrade}" />
            <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding Animals}" />
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Animals}" />
        </StackLayout>

    </ContentPage>
```

**MainPageModel.cs**

```cs
    public class MainPageModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainPageModel()
        {
            _Animals = new List<string>() { "Chicken", "Cow" };
        }

        private List<string> _Animals;
        public List<string> Animals
        {
            get { return _Animals; }
            set
            {
                _Animals = value;

                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Animals"));
            }
        }

        public Command Upgrade
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(_ =>
                {
                    Animals = new List<string>() { "Eagle", "Elephant" };
                });
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

The above code is running XF 4.3.0.908675.  I downgraded to 4.2.0.778463, and the problem goes away.  This might be a new bug introduced in the latest XF release.

Comment: Admittedly a work around, but you could manually clear and re-add the new items to the picker

Comment: Thanks, I actually tried that already.  Same issue.  The CollectionView updates fine.  The Picker does not.

Comment: You mean you removed the items from the picker in code and the items remain?

Comment: Both Picker and CollectionView are bound to the same list.  In the example above I do a new List, but I have tried Animals.Clear() and then adding one by one.  Both methods have the same issue.  I updated the answer, but this appears to be a XF bug.  I downgraded to 4.2.0.778463 and the problem goes away.

Comment: Right, I meant removing items from the picker, not just calling clear on Animals. Or, remove and re-add the binding after the items change.  I have to do this all the time with Xamarin.  its buggy

Comment: Did you file a bug report?

Comment: What happens if you replace `List` with `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: @Jason Yes, I submitted a bug report here https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8177.

Comment: @Prateek List and ObservableCollection have the same behavior.  I actually tried that before going to the trouble submitting this post!

Comment: @John, I download your sample, try to test at my side, it works fine, and picker can update when click button, so strange.

Comment: out of curiosity, do you have Hot Reload enabled? i have the latest xf and pickers work fine

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT I am only experiencing the problem on UWP right now.  Android works fine.  iOS I haven't tried.  What platforms did you try?

Comment: @Ricardo-Dias-Morais Yes, I had Hot Reload enabled.  I tried it again with it disabled.  Same issue unfortunately.  I am only experiencing the problem on UWP right now. Android works fine. iOS I haven't tried.  And it's for version 4.3.0.908675.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been confirmed on the reported channel:[Issue 8177](http://www.github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8177), and I have tried the pre-release version of Xamarin.Forms(4.4.0.991210-pre2), the binding is working fine now on UWP.

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with a similar issue lately, and it does appear to be a XF issue.

I fixed the issue in my app by not setting the list to be a "new List()" but rather to create a separate list and then attach it to the bound list.

In your Command, you should try this:
List newList = new List() { "Eagle", "Elephant" };
Animals = newList;

This might not work for your example, but this did work for me.

Comment: Y, strange that worked.  I tried it just to see, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: There seems to be multiple issues with the picker not updating - I'm using Android which doesn't appear to have the exact same fault.  My implementation involved using .AddRange and then under certain circumstances I was required to remove entries with .Remove.  This no longer updates the picker after upgrading XF but using the implementation I mentioned above fixed the issue for me.